# Location API not returning location id to server

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, pug

I'm following an tutorial where i am supposed to consume an mongoose API using express and display location information to the view. However I am getting an 404 error on the front end everytime i click the button that calls the API request. The source code for this tutorial can be found here. https://github.com/cliveharber/gettingMean-2/tree/chapter-07

Here is the API request handler on the server side:

```js
const getLocationInfo = (req, res, callback) => {
  const path = `/api/locations/${req.params.locationid}`;
  const requestOptions = {
    url: `${apiOptions.server}${path}`,
    method: 'GET',
    json: {}
  };
  request(
    requestOptions,
    (err, {statusCode}, body) => {
      const data = body;
      if (statusCode === 200) {
        data.coords = {
          lng: body.coords[0],
          lat: body.coords[1]
        }
        callback(req, res, data);
      } else {
        showError(req, res, statusCode);
      }
    }
  );
};

const locationInfo = (req, res) => {
  getLocationInfo(req, res,
    (req, res, responseData) => renderDetailPage(req, res, responseData)
  );
};
```

The Render handler of the page i am trying to reach:

```js
const renderDetailPage = (req, res, location) => {
  res.render('location-info',
    {
      title: location.name,
       pageHeader: {
        title: location.name,
      },
      sidebar: {
        context: 'is on Loc8r because it has accessible wifi and space to sit down with your laptop and get some work done.',
        callToAction: 'If you\'ve been and you like it - or if you don\'t - please leave a review to help other people just like you.'
      },
      location
    }
  );
};
```

This is the Mongoose API controller that retrieves the location data from the database:

```js
const locationsReadOne = (req, res) => {
  Loc
    .findById(req.params.locationid)
    .exec((err, location) => {
      if (!location) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({
            "message": "location not found"
          });
      } else if (err) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json(err);
      }
      res 
        .status(200)
        .json(location);
    });
};
```

This is the express routing code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');
const ctrlOthers = require('../controllers/others');

router.get('/', ctrlLocations.homelist);
router.get('/locations/:location._id', ctrlLocations.locationInfo);
```

And finally this is a snippet of the Pug code that contains the button which calls the get request to retrieve the location id:

```html
each location in locations
        .card
          .card-block
            h4
              a(href=`/locations/${location_id}`)= location.name
              +outputRating(location.rating)
              span.badge.badge-pill.badge-default.float-right= location.distance
            p.address= location.address
            .facilities
              each facility in location.facilities
                span.badge.badge-warning= facility
```

Let me know if i need to provide additional information. Appreciate any help.

Comment: A 404 error usually means that there's a problem with your Expressjs routing, but you didn't include any of that code.

Comment: I forgot about the routing code. I'll add that

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to trim down the question a bit to only focus on that part of the problem.  You're less likely to get answers is the community has to filter through dozens of lines of irrelevant code to get to the root problem.

Comment: Well i added everything i thought was relevant. Not sure what to trim down

Comment: Check the GET request in the browser or console.log it on the server. Anything look wrong?

Comment: The GET request is returning a 404 error. The request url becomes: http://localhost:3000/locations/undefined even the routing is supposed to be http://localhost:3000/locations/{location.id}